# Making faster solution for INTEST on Codechef in Python 3

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I have written a program in Python 3 for the [INTEST problem on Codechef](http://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST) (included in question). The program is taking a lot of time (55.76s) in Python 3. The same code takes almost 1/10 of the time time (4.97s) in C.

> The purpose of this problem is to verify whether the method you are
>   using to read input data is sufficiently fast to handle problems
>   branded with the enormous Input/Output warning. You are expected to be
>   able to process at least 2.5MB of input data per second at runtime.
>
> ### Input
>
> The input begins with two positive integers n k (n, k<=107). The next
>   n lines of input contain one positive integer ti, not greater than
>   109, each.
>
> ### Output
>
> Write a single integer to output, denoting how many integers ti are
>   divisible by k.
>
> ### Example
>
> **Input:** 7 3 1 51 966369 7 9 999996 11
>
> **Output:** 4

My questions are:

1. How is it that the Python 3 code is taking so much time or which line of code specifically is taking the most time?
2. Any modifications that can speed up the code?

[My CodeChef submissions with time and code](http://www.codechef.com/status/INTEST,gouravchawla).

```
import sys
__author__ = 'Gourav Chawla'
"""
    Problem Code: INTEST
    Problem URL: http://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST
    Compatability: Python 3.x
"""

n, k = input().split()
n = eval(n)
k = eval(k)

inputVar = 0
count = 0

# inputVar = [eval(x) for x in input().split()]

inputVar = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readlines()))

for i in inputVar:
   if i % k == 0:
       count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: If it works then post it on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Something wrong with their Python 3 installation. The very same code (I just replaced `input()` with `raw_input()`) being submitted as Python 2.7 runs in 25-27 seconds

Comment: Just change in input? No change in print? Because that breaks the code when switching from 2 to 3 or vice versa.

Comment: And let me try it on SPOJ then and see what time do I get.

Comment: @Alik You seem to be right. The result on SPOJ vary by a very big margin. The time came out to be 1.94s

Comment: @GouravChawla something strange is going on on their servers. I've simply copied 14sec solution Python 2 solution and got 29 sec execution time.

Comment: @GouravChawla Python 2 uses `print` statement, but it works with parenthesis https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement So simple `print(count)` will work in Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: Oh, well there I go. The problem wasn't even a problem. One more thing, the code execution time can come out to be different on different judges, right? Because the processing power might be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out to be a problem of codechef judge. The same code gives far less time on SPOJ. Codechef time was in double digits while SPOJ time was in single digit only.